# How to show on a a map of countries only the countries with names contained in a php array

Tags: carto, joomla

I'm doing an important homework for university and I want to use cartoDB to do some parts of it. On my joomla website I have created a form with Chronoforms and in Chronoforms in a custom code box I have written a php code that took the user's data from the form and retrieve some informations
from a database. Now the result is an array of names of countries ordered by some parameters the user gave to me. What I want to do now is to show on my map of countries and provinces only the countries in the array in different colours. the effect should be similar to what I can obtain opening the file html below on a browser web only there are more countries to show,with different colours and the name of the countries are taken from the array.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v2/themes/css/cartodb.ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
  <style>
    html, body {width:100%; height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    #cartodb-map { width: 100%; height:100%; background: white;}
  </style>
  <script>
    var map;
    function init(){
      // initiate leaflet map
      map = new L.Map('cartodb-map', {
        center: [10,10],
        zoom: 3
      })
      var layerUrl = 'http://obiettivolaurea.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/39521542-53a2-11e4-85f3-0e018d66dc29/viz.json' ;
      var subLayerOptions = {
             sql: "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces where admin='Argentina'"
      }
      cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
          .addTo(map)
          .on('done', function(layer) {
              layer.getSubLayer(1).set(subLayerOptions);
          }).on('error', function() {
            //log the error
            });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <div id='cartodb-map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do so?? Someone can help me??

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do two things:

First, rewrite the SQL query to only show the countries contained in the array using the [Array comparison, IN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN16855):

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE country_code IN ('ESP', 'NOR', 'FRA')

Then, provide the CartoCSS to color the geometry of the countries to the subLayerOptions:

> cartocss: '#table_name { [country_code='FRA'] { polygon-fill: #4B80B7 }; [country_code='ESP'] { polygon-fill: #E95748 }}'

Resources:

- [Conditional styling](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/conditional_styling.html)
- [CartoDB.js](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html)
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static)

Comment: Now the subLayerOptions is  var subLayerOptions = {
             sql : "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces WHERE admin IN ('Spain', 'Norway', 'France')",
             cartocss: '#ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces { [admin='France'] { polygon-fill: #4B80B7 }; [admin='Spain'] { polygon-fill: #E95748 }}'
       }
but there must be something wrong with the syntax because it says SyntaxError: missing } after property list
 
...states_provinces { [admin='France'] { polygon-fill: #4B80B7 }; [admin='Spain'] {...

Comment: Another question:the names of the countries are in my array,so I should not insert them manually in the sql statement but it should  be parametric. How can I do it??